# Отрисовка спрайтов в Wolf3D-подобном движке

Tags: c, разработка-игр

Есть наброски псевдо-3d движка на голом си, карта-основа представляет собой двумерный массив из единиц и нулей. Единицы – стены, нули – свободное для "ходьбы" пространство. Так же есть двоечки, которые должны быть спрайтами.

В качестве алгоритма рейкастинга используется пошаговый на косинусах и синусах.
Псевдокод (т.к. задаю вопрос с телефона):

```
Start = pov - 30°
End = start + fov
while (start <= end)
   rayx = playerx
   rayy = playery
   while !wall
      rayx += cos(start)
      rayy += sin(start)
   start += fov/screen_weight
```

вот этим циклом кастуются лучики, дальше отрисовываются (не суть важно как, метод один).

Вопрос: гайды от индусов на ютубчике и прочих ресурсах предлагают отрисовывать спрайты после отрисовки кадра-сцены, запоминая предварительно координаты спрайта на карте и запоминая (в дополнительный массив) длину каждого из брошеных ранее лучей, как например в этом гайде: https://proglib.io/p/raycasting-for-the-smallest .
Есть ли возможность отрисовать и стены и спрайты за один проход лучей? То есть бросил луч, встретил спрайт, записал координаты, луч прошел дальше до стены. Отрисовал вертикальный столбец и сразу же отрисовал столбец спрайта ближе к игроку. Шаг луча дальше по FOV и так далее.
Если есть, то как лучше это реализовать?

Если будет нужна дополнительная информация или код, то сообщите, докину в тред. Прошу извинить за псевдокод в вопросе.

Comment: Да есть, конечно, надо просто считать пересечение луча со спрайтом, как будто тот движущаяся стена с прозрачностью в текстуре.

Comment: @bipll могу ли я уточнить у Вас, как можно корректно миновать прочие стороны спрайта? 
То есть вся карта для алгоритма представляет собой набор квадратов, условно 64х64, в том числе и спрайт. Но спрайту следует быть после рендера не кубом, а плоскостью, всегда повернутой к игроку. Этот же алгоритм рейкастинга будет считать встреченный на карте спрайт таким же кубом, как и стены, что влечет за собой забавные графические аномалии.

Comment: ну так элементарно же. Если встретили спрайт, то дальше нужно двигаться, проверяя, не спрайт ли у нас (если спрайт, то стены не будет). А как только не спрайт, то снова проверяем, не стена ли. (сам писал отрисовку стен по этим же туториалам)